# How to fill dropdown with json data from restful api using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to fill dropdown menu with dates from this [API](http://194.141.118.43:3010/dates)

```
    // Create Asynchronous function to grab the data for filling dropdown
async function getData() {
  try {
    // We are using fetch to get the response
    const response = await fetch('http://194.141.118.43:3010/dates');
    const data = await response.json();

    // Trigger the listData function and pass the result
    listDataDates(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

// Create a function that will insert the data into our legends UL in dropdown
function listDataDates(data) {
  // Loop through each result and append the data.
  data.map(function (clickedDates) {
    const fillDates = `
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">${clickedDates.dataprog}</a></li>`;
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerHTML = fillDates;
    list.appendChild(item);
  });
  // Finally append all the data to the UL.
  ulDates.appendChild(list);
}
```

I try like that but I receive message error: `TypeError: data.map is not a function`

How can I populate the menu with the data with dataprog values from the API ?

```
clickedDates.dataprog
```

not working, what should I put in its place ?

When I use:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
```

at the beginning of the function `listDataDates` I see in the console this data:

```
    {
  "floodguard_dates": {
    "command": "SELECT",
    "rowCount": 6,
    "oid": null,
    "rows": [
      {
        "datprog": "2023-01-20T07:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "datprog": "2023-01-20T06:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "datprog": "2023-01-19T19:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "datprog": "2023-01-19T07:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "datprog": "2023-01-18T07:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "datprog": "2022-02-21T06:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question, showing the results of running `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` at the start of `listDataDates`. `data` is likely not an array.

Comment: Use `data.floodguard.rows`

Comment: ok, but I still receive TypeError: data.map is not a function how can I structure the function ?

Comment: @BenJohnson I think you have to use data['floodguard_dates'].rows instead of directly passing the data object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an object, but `map()` works with arrays. My guess is that you want to iterate through the rows:

```js
data.floodguard_dates.rows.map(...)
```

For example. to get the dates you would do:

```js
const dates = data.floodguard_dates.rows.map(row => row.datprog)
```